# Argument parser object does not contain attribute defined in parser

Tags: python, argparse

I am working on a program that works on hyperspectral image super-resolution by using Neural Networks, Now in here the Mains directory of the program contains multiple parsers. The parsers and subparsers seem to have been defined correctly

```
def main():
# parsers
main_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="parser for SR network")
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="subcommands", dest="subcommand")
train_parser = subparsers.add_parser("train", help="parser for training arguments")
train_parser.add_argument("--cuda", type=int, required=False,default=1,
                          help="set it to 1 for running on GPU, 0 for CPU")
train_parser.add_argument("--batch_size", type=int, default=32, help="batch size, default set to 64")
train_parser.add_argument("--epochs", type=int, default=40, help="epochs, default set to 20")
train_parser.add_argument("--n_feats", type=int, default=256, help="n_feats, default set to 256")
train_parser.add_argument("--n_blocks", type=int, default=3, help="n_blocks, default set to 6")
train_parser.add_argument("--n_subs", type=int, default=8, help="n_subs, default set to 8")
train_parser.add_argument("--n_ovls", type=int, default=2, help="n_ovls, default set to 1")
train_parser.add_argument("--n_scale", type=int, default=4, help="n_scale, default set to 2")
train_parser.add_argument("--use_share", type=bool, default=True, help="f_share, default set to 1")
train_parser.add_argument("--dataset_name", type=str, default="Chikusei", help="dataset_name, default set to dataset_name")
train_parser.add_argument("--model_title", type=str, default="SSPSR", help="model_title, default set to model_title")
train_parser.add_argument("--seed", type=int, default=3000, help="start seed for model")
train_parser.add_argument("--learning_rate", type=float, default=1e-4,
                          help="learning rate, default set to 1e-4")
train_parser.add_argument("--weight_decay", type=float, default=0, help="weight decay, default set to 0")
train_parser.add_argument("--save_dir", type=str, default="./trained_model/",
                          help="directory for saving trained models, default is trained_model folder")
train_parser.add_argument("--gpus", type=str, default="1", help="gpu ids (default: 7)")

test_parser = subparsers.add_parser("test", help="parser for testing arguments")
test_parser.add_argument("--cuda", type=int, required=False,default=1,
                         help="set it to 1 for running on GPU, 0 for CPU")
test_parser.add_argument("--gpus", type=str, default="0,1", help="gpu ids (default: 7)")


args = main_parser.parse_args()

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = args.gpus
print(args.gpus)
if args.subcommand is None:
    print("ERROR: specify either train or test")
    sys.exit(1)
if args.cuda and not torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("ERROR: cuda is not available, try running on CPU")
    sys.exit(1)
if args.subcommand == "train":
    train(args)
else:
    test(args)
pass
```

however, upon using the args object, the compiler throws an error saying that the object has no attribute gpus. Though, the test parser does contain the attribute 'gpus'

```
"G:\Python projects\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "G:/Hyperspectral ISRO/SSPSR-master/mains.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "G:\Hyperspectral ISRO\SSPSR-master\mains.py", line 309, in <module>
    main()
  File "G:\Hyperspectral ISRO\SSPSR-master\mains.py", line 70, in main
    os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = args.gpus
AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'gpus'
```

I cannot figure out as to why this is happening, as I believe I am parsing the arguments correctly before using args, I tried to find similar issues on forums, but failed to do so.

Comment: 'gpus' is only created by a subparser.  During testing include a `print(args)` to better see what the parser has done.  You might also set the `subparsers` to be 'required'

Comment: @hpaulj it outputs `Namespace(subcommand=None)` when i use `print(args)`

Comment: So the `args.subcommand` test has to be first.

Comment: @hpaulj `print(args.subcommand)` returns `none` when I call it.

Comment: That's why you have a `if args.subcommand is None:` test!

Comment: @hpaulj right, however, what puzzles me is that when the `main_parser` contains the `subparsers`, and both the `subparsers` have the attribute `gpus` then why is is not returning a value? As if those attributes are not a part of `main_parser`

Comment: The main parser knows nothing about the arguments defined for the subparsers.  The subparser's arguments are only added to the Namespace when the subparser is called.  Likewise if you call 'test', you won't see any of the arguments defined for 'train'.  Arguments added to a "argument_group' do get added to the parser, but the subparser mechanism is different.

Comment: @hpaulj So, to remedy the issue, i must create seperate objects for each parser and then individually use them where required?

Comment: You can use `main_parser.set_defaults` to provide a value for `gpus` in the event that neither subparser is used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is:

```
args = main_parser.parse_args()
print(args) # for debugging help

if args.subcommand is None:
    print("ERROR: specify either train or test")
    sys.exit(1)

# now it's safe to reference `gpus` and `cuda` which are defined by both subparsers

os.environ['CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'] = args.gpus

if args.cuda and not torch.cuda.is_available():
    print("ERROR: cuda is not available, try running on CPU")
    sys.exit(1)
if args.subcommand == "train":
    train(args)
else:
    test(args)
```

Just beware that `train` and `test` will get different `args`.  `train` won't get any of the `test` values.

Try different command line values and note the differences in the `args`.

if you use

```
subparsers = main_parser.add_subparsers(title="subcommands", dest="subcommand",
     required=True)
```

you don't need to do your own test for `args.subcommand is None`.  The parser will do that for you.